# fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 trying to use dosbox but can't get past the first step

Tags: dosbox

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DOSBox

The first thing I try is:

In a regular terminal, (NOT DOSBox), you can execute

```
mkdir ~/dos/c
```

which will create the  `/dos/c`  directory in your home directory.

I can not do this very simple first step. I get error:

```
cannot create directory
```

Comment: Now the wiki is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use this command:

```
mkdir -p ~/dos/c
```

The -p option will automatically make any parent folders if they don't exist.

The reason the command is failing for you is that you're trying to create "c" inside of the "dos" folder, but the dos folder doesn't exist. You could also work around this by running each command separately:

```
mkdir ~/dos
mkdir ~/dos/c
```